# Submanifolds and adapted atlas

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold of dimension $n$.

My notes say

> **Theorem:** A subset $S$ of $M$  could be given a structure of smooth manifold of dimension $k$ such that $S$ is an embedded submanifold of $M$ (i.e. the inclusione map $\iota:S\hookrightarrow M$ is a smooth embedding) if and only if for each point $p$ in $M$ there exists a smooth chart $(U,\phi)$ for $M$ centered at $p$ and $k$-adapted to $S$ (i.e. $U\cap S=\emptyset$ or $\phi(U\cap S)=\{x\in \phi(U):x^{k+1}=\dots=x^n=0\}$)(Or equivalently: there exists a smooth atlas for $M$ which is $k$-adapted to $S$, meaning that for **each** smooth chart $(U,\phi)$ in that altas, I have $(U,\phi)$ is $k$ adapted to $S$).

Now, in the proof we only show that if I take a point $p$ in $S$ (not, in general, in $M$ as stated above!) then exists a smooth chart $(U_p,\phi_p)$ for $M$ centered at $p$ and $k$-adapted to $S$. But now if I consider $\{(U_p,\phi_p)\}_{p\in S}$ I could not have an atlas for $M$. (I only know that $S\subseteq\bigcup_{p\in S}U_p$ but not that $M=\bigcup_{p\in S}U_p$).

So, the statement of the above theorem is not very correct or am I missing something? How could I complete (if I can!) the set $\{ (U_p,\phi_p)\}_{p\in S}$ to obtain a smooth atlas for $M$ **such that each** chart is $k$-adapted to $S$ ?

Or should I modify the statement in

> > **Theorem:** A subset $S$ of $M$  could be given a structure of smooth manifold of dimension $k$ such that $S$ is an embedded submanifold of $M$ if and only if for each point $p$ in $S$ there exists a smooth chart $(U,\phi)$ for $M$ centered at $p$ and $k$-adapted to $S$ ?

Comment: I am having a really hard time following your question. If $p \not \in S$, then choose a small enough chart which does not intersect $S$ at all. That is a chart "adapted to $S$". That gives you the rest of your charts.

Comment: Is it always possible? If for example $S$ is dense in $M$, then it is not  possible to choose a "small enough  chart which does not intersect $S$ at all".

Comment: That is not an embedded submanifold, and in that case you won't get any adapted charts whatsoever. An embedded submanifold has the subspace topology with respect to the ambient space.

Comment: Shurely something stupid is confusing me, I'm very sorry for this, but in a topological space, a subset could well  be dense in the ambient space and as a space in its own right have the subspace topology. (E.g. Q is dense in R  and has the subspace topology). Now, according to my definition of embedded submanifold, why it is not possibile for $S$ to be dense in $M$?

Comment: Can you explicitly construct a chart in $p$ which does not intersect  $S$ at all?

Comment: It is not a manifold in the subspace topology... if $S$ is dense and of positive codimension, then $S$ equipped with the subspace topology is not a manifold anywhere. You can find subsets (not open!) with a diffeomorphism to $\Bbb R^k \subset \Bbb R^n$ - adapted charts for an embedded submanifolds of $S$ - but other points of $S$ accumulate toward that copy of $\Bbb R^k$.

Comment: I guess one should demand that the embedding is *proper*, though, for the statement to be correct. (This is the same as saying $S$ is closed as a subset of $M$, and the inclusion map is a homeomorphism.) Then you should show that $(M, S)$ admits an atlas of adapted charts if and only if $S$ is a properly embedded submanifold. (This is slightly stronger than demanding that $M$ is embedded: consider the circle without the north pole as a submanifold of $\Bbb R^2$. That has no adapted chart near the deleted point.) It's possible that "the image is closed" was part of your definition of embedding.

Answer (score 1):

The correct statement is that $S \subset M$ is a closed, embedded submanifold if and only if $M$ has an atlas of adapted charts. If I were being careful / if $S$ wasn't embedded a better way to phrase this would be to start by writing $f: S \to M$, which I state is a proper injective immersion.

The essential input into constructing such an atlas is the following.

1) Given any $x \in S$, choose a small chart on $S$ with domain $V$; then there is an open subset $U \subset M$ containing $x$ so that $U \cap S \subset V$. (That is, "far away points of $S$" from the perspective of the manifold topology on $S$ do not accumulate towards some fixed point $f(x)$ in the image.)

2) Given any $x \in M \setminus S$, there should be a neighborhood $U \subset M$ containing $X$ so that $U \cap X = \varnothing$.

The first is necessary so that $f: S \to f(S) \subset M$ is a homeomorphism, where we consider $f(S)$ with the subspace topology (which is guaranteed by the existence of adapted charts near points of $S$). The second is necessary to get adapted charts away from $S$.

---

(2) is equivalent to saying that $S$ is a closed subset of $M$.

(1) is harder: it says that if there is a sequence $x_n \in S$ and $x \in S$ so that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$, then in fact we must have $x_n$ near $x$; that is, there is a subsequence of $x_n$ which converges to $x$. This is saying that the embedding map is "proper": the inverse image of compact sets, like $\{f(x_1), f(x_2), \cdots, f(x)\}$, is compact.

But if $f$ is a proper embedding (= proper injective immersion = injective immersion with closed image), then one may indeed find adapted charts.

The definitions already almost tell us the proof. If $p \in S$, we know that we may find some chart $V \subset S$ of $p$ and some chart $U \subset M$ of $f(p)$ so that on these charts, the map $f: V \cap U \to U$ is given by the inclusion of $\Bbb R^k$ into $\Bbb R^n$, by the implicit function theorem. What we don't know is that $U \cap S = V \cap S$, so that $S$ "never otherwise appears in $U$". This is where your proof needs the properness assumption. This gives an adapted chart to any point $p \in S$.

If $p \not \in S$, then by assumption we may choose a chart with domain $U$ having trivial intersection with $S$. If you already had a chart with domain $U'$, then the new  chart is the same map on the subdomain $U = U' \cap (M \setminus S)$, which is again open.